# Lily pad jumping

Tags: code-golf, string

In this challenge, you need to simulate a frog jumping back and forth on lily pads.  The pond is infinitely big, has a line of an infinite number of lily pads, and the frog can jump across as many lily pads as he likes.

This frog likes to jump back and forth:  **after jumping forward, he always jumps backwards**, and vice versa.

You are passed a list of integers, which represents his jumps.  You need to output the result of his jumps.

For example, say you are passed `[2,3,6,8,2]`:

Our frog starts by jumping 2 lily pads forward:

```
_2
```

Then 3 lily pads back:

```
3__2
```

Then 6 lily pads forward:

```
3__2__6
```

8 back:

```
8_3__2__6
```

Then finally, 2 lily pads forward (notice how the 2 overwrites the 3):

```
8_2__2__6
```

To be more explicit: Your input is an an array of numbers `S`, you need to output `S[K]` at the position `S[K] - S[K-1] + S[K-2] - S[K-3]...`.

- If multiple numbers are to be printed at a certain location, print only the one with the highest index.
- You are to use `_` if a particular location is empty
- If a number has multiple digits, it does not take up multiple locations. (In other words, a location can consist of multiple characters)
- You can assume that your list is non-empty, and that all integers are greater than 0.

## Test cases:

```
5                   ____5
2,2                 2_2
4,3,2,1             3124
5,3,2,1             _3125
2,3,6,8,2           8_2__2__6
10,3,12,4,1,12,16   ___12__3__10____41__1216
100,4,7,2,2         _______________________________________________________________________________________________4___1002_2
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so answer it in as few characters as possible!

Comment: I wonder who watched Numberphile?

Comment: So there's gonna be a challenge for every Numberphile video then...

Comment: [Related](http://www.froggerclassic.appspot.com/) :-P

Comment: @Fatalize I see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Also [related](https://youtu.be/TnjC03Tsg1c?t=7s) ;-)

Comment: `print only the one with the highest index` You mean its index in the input array?

Comment: @smls correct.  I wasn't sure of a clearer way to say that, so if you have any suggestions, I'm all ears :)

Comment: @nderscore sorry, the `__2` was wrong.  Thank you!

Comment: How large is the frog pond? Is there a minimum range size that we are required to support?

Comment: A single jump will never be bigger than your language's maximum integer.  However, there is no maximum on the pond size (outside of memory constraints)

Answer (score 10):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

*Thanks to [@Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna) for saving 1 byte!*

```
32Oittn:oEq*Yst1hX<-Q(Vh' 0'95ZtXz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29s5J9ZUpJnle9aqBVZXGKYEWGjG6gRlqGuYKBuaRpVElH1/3@0kY6xjpmOhY5RLAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#S/hvbOSfWVKSZ5XvWqgVWVximBFhoxuoEZahrmCgbmkaVRJR9d8l5H@0aSxXtImOsY6RjiGQZQpnGQFZZjoWOkZAtqEBkGNopGOiYwiiDM3AYgZAvjlQtVEsAA).

#### How it works

*Golf your code, not your explanations!*

The following uses input `[2,3,6,8,2]` as an example. To see intermediate results in the actual code, you may want to insert a `%` (comment symbol) to stop the program at that point and see the stack contents. For example, [this](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29s5J9ZUpJnle9aqBVZrFpimBFhoxuoEZahrmCgoG5pGlUSUfX/f7SRjrGOmY6FjlEsAA) shows the stack after statement `Ys` (cumulative sum).

```
32       % Push 32 (ASCII for space)
O        % Push 0
i        % Input array
         % STACK: 32, 0, [2,3,6,8,2]
t        % Duplicate
         % STACK: 32, 0, [2,3,6,8,2], [2,3,6,8,2]
tn:      % Push [1 2 ... n] where n is length of input array
         % STACK: 32, 0, [2,3,6,8,2], [2,3,6,8,2], [1,2,3,4,5]
o        % Modulo 2
         % STACK: 32, 0, [2,3,6,8,2], [2,3,6,8,2], [1,0,1,0,1]
Eq       % Multiply by 2, subtract 1
         % STACK: 32, 0, [2,3,6,8,2], [2,3,6,8,2], [1,-1,1,-1,1]
*        % Multiply elementwise
         % STACK: 32, 0, [2,3,6,8,2], [2,-3,6,-8,2]
Ys       % Cumulative sum
         % STACK: 32, 0, [2,3,6,8,2], [2,-1,5,-3,1]
         % The top-most array is the positions where the entries of the second-top
         % array will be written. But postions cannot be less than 1; if that's
         % the case we need to correct so that the minimum is 1. If this happens,
         % it means that the frog has gone further left than where he started
t        % Duplicate
1hX<     % Append 1 and compute minimum. So if the original minimum is less than 1
         % this gives that minimum, and if it is more than 1 it gives 1
         % STACK: 32, 0, [2,3,6,8,2], [2,-1,5,-3,1], -3
-        % Subtract
         % STACK: 32, 0, [2,3,6,8,2], [5 2 8 0 2]
Q        % Add 1
         % STACK: 32, 0, [2,3,6,8,2], [6 3 9 1 3]
(        % Assign values (top array) to specified positions (second-top) into array
         % which contains a single 0 (third-top). Newer values overwrite earlier
         % values at the same position
         % STACK: 32, [8 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 6]
V        % Convert to string. This produces spaces between the numbers
         % STACK: 32, '8 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 6'
h        % Concatenate with initial 32 (space). This converts to char
         % STACK: ' 8 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 6'
         % Thanks to this initial space, all zeros that need to be replaced by '_'
         % are preceded by spaces. (In this example that initial space would not
         % be needed, but in other cases it will.) Other zeros, which are part of
         % a number like '10', must not be replaced
' 0'     % Push this string: source for string replacement
         % STACK: ' 8 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 6', ' 0 '
95       % Push 95 (ASCII for '_'): target for string replacement
         % STACK: ' 8 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 6', ' 0 ', 95
Zt       % String replacement
         % STACK: ' 8_2__2__6'
Xz       % Remove spaces. Implicit display
         % STACK: '8_2__2__6'
```

Comment: I think you could save two bytes by replacing `'0'` instead of `' 0 '`, because `Xz` removes the spaces after

Comment: @B.Mehta Thanks. I initially did that, but unfortunately it doesn't work, because then the `'0'` in `'10'` gets replaced too. That's why I add an initial `32` too

Comment: Ah of course, my mistake

Comment: @B.Mehta No, it wasn't clear at all from my explanation. I'll clarify that later

Comment: The mod 2 array is inverted in the explanation. And also, wouldn't `' 0'` work just as well?

Comment: @Emigna Thanks; and yes, extra thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>100</s> <s>97</s> 96 bytes

```
function(x){p=cumsum(x*c(1,-1))[seq(x^0)]
p=p+max(1-p,0)
v=rep('_',max(p));v[p]=x
cat(v,sep='')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU3LCoMwELz7Fbllt10hSa0t2HyJtUWCQg9q6ouA9NvTCEWkl53HzjC9r9ktZr6eWjO@uhYcLlabqRmmBtzBgKRYIuZD9Qb3EFhEVttjUzqQsSWB0az7ygJ/clpNi5jNuS20i0w5wkxDZTXn@PHdNK5Dux221OFmbA3yextCUQiBgTPijylSG0/oRIrkps9/WgWd0nXXkCJYUlFCcgWZ7j4iuJfQVwzR@y8)

Line 1 finds all positions where to jump. First, all jumps in `x` are multiplied by 1 or −1 and then transformed to final positions using cumulative summation. The vector `c(-1,1)` is recycled if necessary, however, when `x` is of length 1, `x` is recycled instead. Therefore only `seq(x^0)` (equivalent to `seq_along(x)`) sums are considered. (A warning is generated when the length of `x` is not a multiple of 2 but it does not affect the result)

Line 2 increases the jumping positions so that all are at least 1.

Lines 3 and 4 create the output and print it.

*−1 byte from [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)*

Comment: neat trick with `seq(x^0)`!

Comment: `-p+1` can be `1-p` for one byte less.

Comment: @Giuseppe Ah, definitely, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>100</s> <s>101</s> <s>99</s> 104 bytes

```php
for($p=-1;$d=$argv[++$k];+$i<$p?:$i=$p,$x>$p?:$x=$p)$r[$p+=$k&1?$d:-$d]=$d;for(;$i<=$x;)echo$r[$i++]?:_;
```

takes input from command line arguments; run with `-nr`.

**breakdown**

```php
for($p=-1;          // init position
    $d=$argv[++$k]; // loop $d through command line arguments
    +$i<$p?:$i=$p,          // 3. $i=minimum index
    $x>$p?:$x=$p            // 4. $x=maximum index
)
    $r[
        $p+=$k&1?$d:-$d     // 1. jump: up for odd indexes, down else
    ]=$d;                   // 2. set result at that position to $d
for(;$i<=$x;)           // loop $i to $x inclusive
    echo$r[$i++]?:_;        // print result at that index, underscore if empty
```

Comment: How does this handle the example input `2,3,6,8,2`, where the `8` jumps "backwards" past the "beginning" of the lily pads?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork PHP supports negative array indexes.

Comment: Ah, did not know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>99</s> 107 bytes

*Edit: Because the OP clarified that the only limit should be the available memory, this was updated to allocate exactly the required space instead of relying on a hardcoded maximum range.*

```js
f=(a,x='',p=M=0)=>a.map(n=>x[(p-=(i=-i)*n)<m?m=p:p>M?M=p:p]=n,i=m=1)&&x?x.join``:f(a,Array(M-m).fill`_`,-m)
```

#### How it works

This function works in two passes:

- During the first pass:

  - The 'frog pointer' `p` is initialized to `0`.
  - The `x` variable is set to an empty string, so that all attempts to modify it are simply ignored.
  - We compute `m` and `M` which are respectively the minimum and maximum values reached by `p`.
  - At the end of this pass: we do a recursive call to `f()`.
- During the second pass:

  - `p` is initialized to `-m`.
  - `x` is set to an array of size `M-m`, filled with `_` characters.
  - We insert the numbers at the correct positions in `x`.
  - At the end of this pass: we return a joined version of `x`, which is the final result.

#### Test cases

```js
f=(a,x='',p=M=0)=>a.map(n=>x[(p-=(i=-i)*n)<m?m=p:p>M?M=p:p]=n,i=m=1)&&x?x.join``:f(a,Array(M-m).fill`_`,-m)

console.log(f([5]));                  // ____5
console.log(f([4,3,2,1]));            // 3124
console.log(f([5,3,2,1]));            // _3125
console.log(f([2,3,6,8,2]));          // 8_2__2__6
console.log(f([10,3,12,4,1,12,16]));  // ___12__3__10____41__1216
console.log(f([100,4,7,2,2]));        // _..._4___1002_2
```

Comment: This fails for cases where the frog jumps below index -998 or above 1002. Example: `[1100]` results in the number printed at position `1002` instead of position `1100`.

Comment: @nderscore This is fixed, at the cost of 8 bytes.

Comment: awesome! nice method also :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>28</s>  24 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 (and further allowing another -2) thanks to FrownyFrog (use the [post-challenge] functionality of the prefix application quick, `Ƥ`)

```
ṚƤḅ-µCṀ»0+µṬ€×"³Ṛo/o”_;⁷
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUMAvP9qZWxsef//4bmaxqThuIUtwrVD4bmAwrswK8K14bms4oKsw5ciwrPhuZpvL2/igJ1fO@KBt////1syLDMsNiw4LDJd)** Full program, for a test suite using the same functionality, click [here](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlnHljzc0ap7aKvzw50Nh3YbaB/a@nDnmkdNa7gOT1c63A5UkK@f/6hhbrz1o8btXIfbgTL///@PjjaN1Yk20jECkiY6xjpGOoZAlimcZQRkmelYgOUNDYAcQyMdEx1DEGVoBhYzAPLNdUAmxAIA).

#### How?

```
ṚƤḅ-µCṀ»0+µṬ€×"³Ṛo/o”_;⁷ - Main link: list a       e.g. [ 5, 3, 2, 1]
 Ƥ                       - prefix application of:
Ṛ                        -  reverse                e.g. [[5],[3,5],[2,3,5],[1,2,3,5]]
   -                     - literal minus one
  ḅ                      - from base (vectorises)  e.g. [ 5, 2, 4, 3]=
    µ                    - start a new monadic chain - call that list c
                         - [code to shift so minimum is 1 or current minimum]
     C                   - complement (vectorises) e.g. [-4,-1,-3,-2]
      Ṁ                  - maximum                 e.g.     -1
       »0                - maximum of that & zero  e.g.      0
         +               - add to c (vectorises)   e.g. [ 5, 2, 4, 3]
          µ              - start a new monadic chain - call that list d
           Ṭ€            - untruth €ach            e.g. [[0,0,0,0,1],[0,1],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1]]
               ³         - the program input (a)
             ×"          - zip with multiplication e.g. [[0,0,0,0,5],[0,3],[0,0,0,2],[0,0,1]]
                Ṛ        - reverse                      [[0,0,1],[0,0,0,2],[0,3],[0,0,0,0,5]]
                 o/      - reduce with or          e.g. [0,3,1,2,5]
                    ”_   - '_'
                   o     - or (replace 0 with '_') e.g. ['_',3,1,2,5]
                      ;⁷ - concatenate a newline   e.g. ['_',3,1,2,5, '\n']
                         - implicit print
```

Notes:

The final concatenation of a newline, `;⁷` is for cases when no `_` appear in the output, in which case the implicit print would display a representation of the list, e.g. `[3, 1, 2, 4]`, rather than something like the example, `_3125`. For no trailing newline one could replace `;⁷` with `;““` to append a list of character lists, `[[''],['']]` (no close `”` required as it's the last character of a program).

The untruth function, Ṭ, gives a list with `1`s at the indexes in it's input, for a single natural number, **n** that is **n-1** `0`s followed by a `1` allowing the input numbers to be placed at their correct distance from the left by multiplication. The reversal, `Ṛ`, is required to have *later* frog-visits overwrite rather than *earlier* ones when the reduction with or, `o/`, is performed.

Comment: ``1,-ṁ×µ+\``→``UƤ_@/€`` ?

Comment: `Ƥ` was not a feature at the point this was written, but yes that will work. Better is `UƤḅ€-` (since conversion from base -1 is like multiplying by `...,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1` and then summing).

Comment: ...or even `UƤḅ-` since `ḅ` vectorises :) (I also went with plain reverse, `Ṛ`, since we don't need the complexity of upend, `U`)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), <s>68</s> 67 bytes

```perl6
{(my @a)[[[\+] |(1,-1)xx*Z*$_].&{$_ X-min 1,|$_}]=$_;[~] @a X//"_"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#XczBCoJAEAbgu08xyCKrjelsaoEIPYa0LYsHhQ52kUJRe/VtgsDoND/fPzOPoYVnUXr9BEEHlZslp3MTaq2vOwOLJIwpHMfoEglr9sEsLNRxf7sD4SLsaiphS/0yfAN1kvjWX93QTNCBzMPS@8YMD6iQNsj/QTEUeEK1EaVspDBD@gwqfquU@cgveN@9AQ)

#### How it works

First it determines the cumulative jump locations:

```perl6
[[\+] |(1,-1)xx*Z*$_]
                  $_  # Input array.          e.g.  2, 3, 6, 8, 2
      |(1,-1)xx*      # Infinite sequence:          1,-1, 1,-1, 1...
                Z*    # Zip-multiplied.       e.g.  2,-3, 6,-8, 2
 [\+]                 # Cumulative addition.  e.g.  2,-1, 5,-3,-1
```

Then it turns them into 0-based array indices by subtracting the minimum number (but at most 1) from all the numbers:

```perl6
.&{$_ X-min 1,|$_}    #                       e.g.  5, 2, 8, 0, 2
```

Then it creates an array with the input numbers assigned to those indices:

```perl6
(my @a)[   ]=$_;      #                       e.g.  8, Nil, 2, Nil, Nil, 2 Nil, Nil, 6
```

Finally it concatenates the array to a string, with the underscore in place of undefined elements:

```perl6
[~] @a X//"_"         #                       e.g.  8_2__2__6
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (ES6), 109 bytes

```js
f=x=>x.map((y,i)=>o[j=(j-=i%2?y:-y)<0?o.unshift(...Array(-j))&0:j]=y,o=[],j=-1)&&[...o].map(y=>y||'_').join``
```

```html
<!-- snippet demo: -->
<input list=l oninput=console.log(f(this.value.split(/,/)))>
<datalist id=l><option value=5><option value="4,3,2,1"><option value="5,3,2,1"><option value="2,3,6,8,2"><option value="10,3,12,4,1,12,16"><option value="100,4,7,2,2"></datalist>
```

#### Commented:

```js
f=x=>x.map((y,i)=>o[j=(j-=i%2?y:-y)<0?o.unshift(...Array(-j))&0:j]=y,o=[],j=-1)&&[...o].map(y=>y||'_').join``
                /* initialize output array [] and index j at -1: */  o=[],j=-1
     x.map((y,i)=> /* iterate over all items in input x (y=item, i=index) */  )
                      (j-=i%2?y:-y) /* update j +/-y based on if index i is odd */
                                   <0? /* if resulting j index is less than zero */
                                      o.unshift(...Array(-j)) /* prepend -j extra slots to the output array */
                                                             &0 /* and give result 0 */
                                                               :j /* else give result j */
                    j= /* assign result to j */
                  o[ /* assign y to output array at index j */   ]=y
   /* short-circuit && then spread output array to fill any missing entries */ &&[...o]
                                                      /* fill falsey slots with '_' */ .map(y=>y||'_')
                                                                         /* join with empty spaces */ .join``
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>45</s> 30 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
{∊⍕¨⍵@i⍴∘'_'⌈/1+i←(⊢-1⌊⌊/)-\⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tU8xasNAEOz1ius2wQjfns6KSOWHBA5BUBARyBg1IbgLQVZ8wY3Btas8IG5S5in7EXlOgdjYtYfldtmZHebyWRU/vuRV/dTL56as5X2t@wLvq7Sd@M3vl/j9tBT/Le2WHMmqHfOohOBGul3MsupQ49v4AbpF3zfDqd/LcjfHWIj/uaciLyvChP1cPt6ofqZFNFFnaMgBE4qMMueMcYYiqxIwfLpP2FiC1QXhwAxWiUpVdjRsKHPGhUopYg2ajbK4ReN0iMAgEzQd4lgOCx7EGsI79Z/uL@8VYUMYrcPfDw)

`-\⍵` scan the argument with alternating `-` and `+`

`(⊢ - 1 ⌊ ⌊/)` from that (`⊢`) subtract 1 or the minimum (`⌊/`), whichever is smaller (`⌊`)

`i←` assign to `i`

`⌈/ 1+` increment and take the maximum

`⍴∘'_'` produce that many underscores

`⍵@i` put the numbers from the argument (`⍵`) at positions `i`

`∊⍕¨` format each and flatten

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 85 bytes

```ruby
->a{i=1;j=c=0;a.map{|x|[c-=x*i=-i,x]}.to_h.sort.map{|x,y|[?_*[x+~j,0*j=x].max,y]}*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZDRasMwDEXf@xXFL4VMCZbjZIWi7UOEMVlYaQKlpfPAJc5@PbOTUVjX110MAt0jdOXL59t12tOUvzRDR7jrqSW5a4pjcx6CD9zm5LOO8g68GQt3sofi43RxPz5cA7/ajP3TVw8y68mb6MS2GbPNZpx4xVwZWP@VsFGVMBAJBeoBI5RVi6@hBAV4x4gSlV6A6jFgI3FbUUIN27tFYmuVTa9eKJQRQwUaMBWsZzpFxQiVscgUW2Nq4G1IxoFn@H3FfN8/SqdQUs5/tDLFe9MehuDCeb1nx9IYIsdoxukb)

Records the positions after each jump, converts the resulting array to hash to remove duplicates (preserving the last value at each duplicated position), and then glues the values with the required amount of underscores.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>113</s> 110 bytes

```python
J=input()
i=sum(J)
l=['_']*2*i
v=i,
d=1
for j in J:i+=d*j;d=-d;l[i]=`j`;v+=i,
print''.join(l[min(v):max(v)+1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpLDsIgFEDROavojE/RCBoHJW8D3QIh1oQYH@GX2ja6emwn90xu/S3vknVrI2Cu68I4QfisiY2cRLD0QZ3QAskGKIkHRV5l7kKHuRsH7MGLYDycvIkWHUxhMlt/nHXGvFB6DgUzizbt3fiQnt@dXjnemlUXeZVKy5tUB@ru/g)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 36 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Z·'_иsvy®yNÈi+ë-}©ǝ®0‹i¤®Äиy0©ǝì]¤ÜJ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUwAs/9vc2FiaWX//1rCtydf0LhzdnnCrnlOw4hpK8OrLX3Cqcedwq4w4oC5acKkwq7DhNC4eTDCqcedw6xdwqTDnEr//1syLDMsNiw4LDJd) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXS/6hD29XjL@woLqs8tK7S73BHpvbh1bq1h1Yen3toncGjhp2Zh5YcWne45cKOSgOQ4OE1sYeWHJ7j9V9JL0zHUOPQypj/0dGmsTrRRjpGQNJEx1jHSMcQyDKFs4yALDMdC7C8oQGQY2ikY6JjCKIMzcBiBkC@uQ7IhFgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Z               # Get the maximum of the (implicit) input-list (without popping)
 ·              # Double it
  '_и          '# Pop and push a list with 2*max amount of "_"
s               # Swap so the input-list is at the top
 v              # Loop over each of its integers `y`:
  y             #  Push the current integer `y`
  ®             #  Push integer `®` (-1 the first iteration)
   y            #  Push integer `y` again
    N           #  Push the 0-based loop-index
     Èi         #  If the index is even:
       +        #   Add the `y` to `®`
      ë         #  Else (the index is odd):
       -        #   Subtract the `y` from `®` instead
      }         #  Close the if-else clause
       ©        #  Store it as new `®` (without popping)
  ǝ             #  Insert the `y` at this index `®` in the "_"-list
                #  (no-op with pops if index `®` is out of bounds, e.g. negative)
  ®0‹i          #  If `®` is negative (<0):
      ¤         #   Push the last item "_" (without popping the list)
       ®Ä       #   Push the absolute value of `®`
         и      #   Pop both and push a list with that amount of "_"
          y     #   Push integer `y` again
           0    #   Push 0
            ©   #   Replace `®` with this 0 (without popping)
             ǝ  #   Insert the `y` at index 0 in the second "_"-list
              ì #   Prepend the two lists together
 ]              # Close both the if-statement and loop
  ¤             # Push the last item "_" again (without popping the list)
   Ü            # Trim all trailing "_" from the list
    J           # Join the list together
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

`NÈi+ë-}` could alternatively be `„+-Nè.V` for the same byte-count: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##AU0Asv9vc2FiaWX//1rCtydf0LhzdnnCrnnigJ4rLU7DqC5WwqnHncKuMOKAuWnCpMKuw4TQuHkwwqnHncOsXcKkw5xK//9bMiwzLDYsOCwyXQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXS/6hD29XjL@woLqs8tK7yUcM8bV2/wyv0wg6tPD730DqDRw07Mw8tObTucMuFHZUGIMHDa2IPLTk8x@u/kl6YjqHGoZUx/6OjTWN1oo10jICkiY6xjpGOIZBlCmcZAVlmOhZgeUMDIMfQSMdExxBEGZqBxQyAfHMdkAmxAA).

```python
    „+-         #  Push string "+-"
       Nè       #  (Modulair) index the loop-index into it
         .V     #  Evaluate and execute this character as 05AB1E code
```